# Checking when an $a$-dependent function is continuous, differentiable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

For some $a\in \Bbb{R}$ define a function $f_{a}(x) =
\begin{cases}
{x^{a}\cos{1\over x}},  & \text{if $x$ $\ne$ 0} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$. Hints firstly are preferred.

b. For what values of $a$ is $f_{a}(x)$ continuous at $\Bbb{R}$?

$Attempt$: $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\cos{1\over x}$ does not exist. Hence, $\cos{1\over x}$ is not continuous at 0. In order for $f$ to be continuous at $\Bbb{R}$, $f$ has to be continuous at $0$. Let us look at $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}x^{a}\cos{1\over x}$.
Where $a\ge0$ $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}x^{a}\cos{1\over x}=\lim_\limits{x\to 0}x^{a}\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\cos{1\over x}=0$
But when $a<0$, $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}x^{a}\cos{1\over x}=\lim_\limits{x\to 0}x^{a}\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\cos{1\over x}=\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{1\over x^{-a}}\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\cos{1\over x}$ does not exist. So $f$ is continuous everywhere when $a>0$.

c. For what values of $a$ is $f_{a}(x)$ differentiable at $\Bbb{R}$?

d. For what values of $a$ is $f'_{a}(x)$ continuous at $\Bbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

*Part b):* You are essentially correct in part $b$, but the limit argument you use is not good. In particular, there are problems with $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}x^a\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\cos\frac{1}{x}=0$ since the latter limit does not exist. Here's how you can do it precisely. Let $a>0$, then $x^a$, $\cos(x)$, and $\frac{1}{x}$ are all continuous functions except at $x=0$. Now since the composition and product of continuous functions is continuous, we know $x^a\cos\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous except potentially at $x=0$.

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\left|x^a\cos\frac{1}{x}\right|\le\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\left|x^a\right|=0$$

On the other hand, if $a<0$, then we can check the sequence of points in the form $x=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ to see that the function is not continuous at $0$. Additionally, for the $a=0$ case, we can say that the limit at $0$ doesn't exist by considering points of the form $x=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$, and $x=\frac{1}{\pi+2\pi n}$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

We can do parts c and d with similar arguments.

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel Well, so when $a=0$, we are only considering $f(x)=\cos\frac{1}{x}$, so if $x_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$, then $f(x_n)=\cos(2\pi n)=1$ for every $x_n$. On the other hand, if $y_n=\frac{1}{\pi+2\pi n}$, then $f(y_n)=\cos(\pi+2\pi n)=-1$. This is a problem because $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n=0$, so if $f(x)$ were continuous at $0$, then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(y_n)$, but this is not the case. Does this make sense?

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much. 
Should I infer that since Thank you. When you talk about the case $a=0$, how did you intend to show discontinuity? What should I do with those sequences? 
Should I infer that since $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}{({1\over 2 \pi n})^0\cdot \cos2\pi n}=1$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}{({1\over 2\pi n})^0\cdot \cos2\pi n+\pi}=0$ then $f$ is not continuous?

Comment: I see... Saying it the way I did is admissible as well?

Comment: OMG what an annoying bug

Comment: And when it comes to c., should I be looking at the continuity of $f'$ or at limits of the form $\lim_\limits{x\to y}{f(x)-f(y)\over x-y}$?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel For your first question, yes, that way of saying it is also fine (though you should make the $\cos(2\pi n+\pi)$ limit be $-1$ instead of $0$) - since the limits aren't the same, $f$ cannot be continuous at $0$.

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel For your second question, you should be using $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow y}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$, however, you can also argue again that since $x^a$, $\cos(x)$, and $\frac{1}{x}$ are differentiable everywhere except $0$, the only problem point you might have is at $0$, so it suffices to check for which $a$ the derivative at $0$ exists - this would mean just checking $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel Glad to help :)

Comment: Peter sorry for disturbing, but in c. I got differentiability at $a>0$ only. At d. should I be looking at the $g=f'$ function continuity? Because looking at it I get continuity when $a<2$. Should I merge the lines?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel I think you should get something else for part c. When you take $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow}\frac{f(x)}{x}$, you should get that this is the same as $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}x^{a-1}\cos\frac{1}{x}$, so this answer would be the same as in part b, except shifted by $1$, so you should get that it is differentiable when $a>1$. I'm afraid I don't know what you mean when you say merge the lines

Comment: But this is not the derivative... Only a part of it... How does it follow?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel for part c, I am using the definition of the derivative as $f'(y)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow y}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$. I then argued that all we had to check was for which values of $a$ the derivative at $0$ existed. Applying the definition of the derivative, you can find that $f'(0)$ exists iff $a>1$. It's in part d where you have to use the rest of the derivative. You get something like $ax^{a-1}\cos\frac{1}{x}+x^{a-2}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ and then this is continuous at $0$ only when $a>2$, basically by the same arguments as before.

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel In short, part c is asking when the derivative exists at $0$ while part d asks whether the derivative is also continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The three questions correspond to levels of squeezing of the $\cos \frac{1}{x}$ wildness at $x=0$

Comment: It does get extremely wild, but I don't see how it interferes continuity.

Comment: With $a=0,$ ie. no squeezing, the function is definitely not continuous at $x=0$

Comment: $sin{1\over x}$ also goes wild but is continuous :(
That is so confusing...

Comment: oh it isn't... At 0

Comment: I edited it using you hint.. How is it?